# How to update angular data without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I have some data in a database table that I used angular to show it. And I use the following script *which is in the footer* to do that:

```
 <script !src="">
var app = angular.module('enterprise', []);

app.controller('entercontroller', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.loadData= function(){

        $http.post('<?php echo base_url(); ?>Groups_/load_data')
            .then(function(mydata){
                console.log(mydata);

                $scope.datas = mydata.data;

            });
    };
    $scope.loadData();
});
</script>
```

And my load_data() function in my controller like:

```
 public function load_data(){
    $data["groups"] = $this->Groups->fetch_groups();
    return $this->output
    ->set_status_header(200)
    ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
    ->set_output(json_encode($data["groups"], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
}
```

And my view is some inputs with submit button. What I need is when I click on the button to add a new record the table is automatically updated without refreshing the page each time. So I make another script to do so

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add').on('submit', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $dataString = that.serialize();             
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'+ $("#uri").val() ,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache:false,
        data : $dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#message').html(data['message']);
            $(':input','#add')
              .removeAttr('checked')
              .removeAttr('selected')
              .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden, :radio, :checkbox')
              .val('');
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;            
});
});
</script>
```

HTML code like:

```
<div class="page-wrapper" ng-app="enterprise" ng-controller="entercontroller">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <form class="floating-labels m-t-40" method="post" id="add" action="addgroup">
                        <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                            <input type="text" name="group_title" class="form-control input-lg" id="input8" required><span class="bar"></span>
                            <label for="input8">Group Name</label><br />
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                            <input type="text" name="group_link" class="form-control input-lg" id="input7" required><span class="bar"></span>
                            <label for="input7">Link</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group m-b-40">
                            <select name="group_icon_code" class="custom-select form-control" id="location1" required >
                                <option value="">Icon</option>
                                <?php
                                if(isset($icons))
                                    foreach($icons as $icon)
                                        echo '<option value="'.$icon->icon_value.'">'.$icon->icon_name.'</option>';
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-xs-right">
                            <input type="hidden" id="uri" name="uri" value="Groups_/addgroup" />
                            <button type="submit" ng-click="loadData()" name="add" value="1" class="btn btn-success"> <i class="fa fa-check"></i> save</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-inverse"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table color-bordered-table inverse-bordered-table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>title</th>
                                    <th>link</th>
                                    <th>order</th>
                                    <th>icon</th>
                                    <th class="text-nowrap">control</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="d in datas">
                                    <td>{{ d.group_title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ d.group_link }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ d.group_order }}</td>
                                    <td><i class="mdi {{ d.group_icon_code }}"></i></td>
                                    <td class="text-nowrap">
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"> <i class="fa fa-pencil text-inverse m-r-10"></i> </a>
                                        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"> <i class="fa fa-close text-danger"></i> </a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to put angular script in the on click function but it doesn't work.
What I need is to reload the same location again after adding.
Any ideas.

Comment: First prepare the api, then prepare the view, make ng-repeat there, and later,make api request to put something inside and api request to get data and put back to model. No jQuery needed. Take a look on any todo app, how is it made.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is mostly used for two way data binding, which seems to be what you are looking for. There should be no need for using JQuery for updating your data if you are using Angular. All variables declared inside your `$scope` refresh automatically when being changed

---

So you are already posting data when loading the angular controller.
I would include that inside a function attached to the scope, so when clicking the button, you post your object and insert it afterwards in the table.

```js
var app = angular.module('enterprise', []);

app.controller('entercontroller', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.tableData = [{ text: "First row" }, { text: "second row" }];

  $scope.loadData = function () {
    // here you do your http post
    var newRow = { text: "New Row" };
    $scope.tableData.push(newRow); // do this inside your http callback function
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body ng-app="enterprise" ng-controller="entercontroller">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData">
      <td>
        {{row.text}}
      </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
  <button ng-click="loadData()">
    Load data
  </button>
</body>
```

Comment: I just Edit my question, only the angular script part to be the same way you told me to do, but it create new `<tr></tr>` with empty `<td></td>`. I don't know if you get my question right. I need the new record I added in my database to be shown in the table of my browser. I thought when I call the controller function that fetch my data that will be it. Thanks any  way.

Comment: If you want to show your posted object in the table, this is the way to go. The `{{row}}` makes reference to a string. If you have an object you would have to write `<td> {{row.attribute}} </td>` for each attribute you want to display. Also, you shouldn't put your post outside a function because this will execute the post when your script is loading.

Comment: The `ng-repeat` attribute will automatically add your posted object to the table.

Comment: I already did what you just said. The problem is when I add a new record. Only the new record doesn't appear at all, only appears when I refresh the page. As if it skip `$http.post('http://localhost/clinic/Groups_/load_data')` to be loaded again.

Comment: Did you add the ng-click tag to your button? It would be helpful to see your html code if you need more help

Comment: If you want to do it the angular way you should associate an `ng-model` with each input. (`ng-model="yourFormObject.yourAttribute"`). Then you can easily add this object to your table array after posting the form.

Comment: What about getting my data through my fetch function, specially their is some data I get from database table I don't add them from the form.

Comment: In this case your backend should return the whole object, either in a new http query or in the post itself. Then you can add it to your html table

Comment: When I click submit button, the object is there _in the console_ but without the new record I have just added. what I need to do is to reload this page `$http.post('http://localhost/clinic/Groups_/load_data')` to update the object that I fetch from there.

Comment: Your post should only be used for sending data, or at most returning the updated object. If you want to load the table data use a http get function. For further help you should ask another question or try things out on your own. Since your original question about reloading data without refreshing the website has been answered, an upvote and accepted answer would be appreciated :) Also, I recommend you looking into some AngularJS tutorials online. Good luck!

Comment: But my original question about reloading data without refreshing the website hasn't been answered :). The inserted record doesn't  add in the browser table till I refresh the page or click the button twice.

Comment: So if you click your button twice it works? I'm not going to write the application for you. With some googling you should be able to figure it out for yourself. I already tried to help you to a great extend and explained you basic AngularJS rules.

Comment: I get the problem. It execute `$scope.loadData` first before the `on('submit')` Ajax. That is why the browser view that data before adding. So, how can I make it in reversal way?!

Comment: You should get rid of the ajax method. The angular $http post is doing that for you. Also, for fetching data you should use GET and for posting data POST.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refresh the list of your data in your table after your transaction, you can use this script. You don't need to add refresh function on your add button. Use this on your load data.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.IntervalTime = 2000;
  $scope.updatedData = 0;

  timeoutFn();

  function timeoutFn() {
    $timeout(function() {

      //Add your select data query here

      $scope.updatedData++; 

      timeoutFn();

    }, $scope.IntervalTime);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <table style="width:50%; height: 50%;">
       <tr>
          <th>Data</th>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td>{{updatedData}}</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<style>
    table, th, td {
         border: 1px solid black;
         text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

Note: Your table will refresh on every 2sec and load the updated select data as I set this to $scope.Interval you can change the interval based on what you want.